# Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 tables A, B, C and D and inner join is performed on same column headings. r is a date type column present in table D and fromVar and toVar are two different dates passed as a parameter

```
SELECT A.m , B.n , B.o , B.p, B.q, C.q
FROM A a 
INNER JOIN B b on B.m = a.m 
INNER JOIN D d ON b.m = d.m
INNER JOIN C c1 on c1.s = a.s 
INNER JOIN C c2 on c2.s = D.s
WHERE C.r BETWEEN TO_DATE(:fromvar,"yyyy-MM-dd" "HH:mm:ss.SSS") AND TO_DATE(:tovar,"yyyy-MM-dd" "HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```

Getting missing right parenthesis error for this query in oracle

Comment: There seems to be no error in your simplified example.

Comment: Your date format needs to be a single string, not separate strings for the date and time portions

Answer (score 3):

The date format masks should each be a single string enclosed in single quotes, not two strings in double quotes; and you need the Oracle format model elements not Java/C/etc. ones; and if your strings have fractional seconds then you have to treat them as timestamps not dates. So:

```
to_timestamp(:fromvar, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

If you are comparing against a date column then the fractional seconds won’t be relevant but still need to be handled by the conversion.

Comment: That gave me a invalid identifier error

Comment: With single quotes? If so check the table and column names are all correct. Which identifier did it say was invalid?

Answer (score 1):

If `:fromVar` and `:toVar` are being passed in from an external source (i.e. Java, C, etc) then pass them in directly as timestamp values (and not strings):

```sql
SELECT A.m , B.n , B.o , B.p, B.q, C.q
FROM   A a
       INNER JOIN B b on B.m = a.m 
       INNER JOIN D d ON b.m = d.m
       INNER JOIN C c1 on c1.s = a.s 
       INNER JOIN C c2 on c2.s = D.s
WHERE  C.r BETWEEN :fromvar AND :tovar
```

If you must pass them as strings then, as Alex said, use one, single-quoted string with the correct format model:

```sql
SELECT A.m , B.n , B.o , B.p, B.q, C.q
FROM   A a 
       INNER JOIN B b on B.m = a.m 
       INNER JOIN D d ON b.m = d.m
       INNER JOIN C c1 on c1.s = a.s 
       INNER JOIN C c2 on c2.s = D.s
WHERE  C.r BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP(:fromvar, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
               AND TO_TIMESTAMP(:tovar,   'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```